# Iterate with ng-options in a dictionary(object)

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I need to iterate over the following object with ng-options:

```
var a = {
'optionName1': 'optionValue1',
'optionName2': 'optionValue2',
'optionName3': 'optionValue3',
'optionName4': 'optionValue4',
};
```

I get this object in this format from a 3rd party resource, and I'd rather no to re-arrange it manually.

I already did a Google search, and looked into the documentation, it deals with lists, and lists of objects only from what I could tell.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a model like this:

```
$scope.options = {
    'optionName1': 'optionValue1',
    'optionName2': 'optionValue2',
    'optionName3': 'optionValue3',
    'optionName4': 'optionValue4',
};
```

You can create options like this:

```
<select ng-change="change()" ng-model="votes.status" 
ng-options="v for (k,v) in options">
</select>
```

Comment: My bad, didn't had ng-model set up.
Probably was too hungry before launch time

Comment: And the parentheses `(k,v)` matter.

Comment: Huh. Thats almost pythonesque. Neat.

Comment: Good! Only one thing to point out is that you can rename as you like, maybe `k` and `v` doesn't make any sense to you. You can do something like this: `ng-options="value for (id,value) in options`

Comment: This is working, however, the ng-model get's Value ('optionValue1') what if we need to show Value in dropdown, but upon selection, model should get key. For example, upon selection of 'optionValue1' the model should hold 'optionName1'

Comment: i think it should be `k for (k,v) in options`